# error: initializer element is not constant when initializing a structure by a function address

Tags: c, linux, gcc, struct

When I compile the the following code I get

```
error: initializer element is not constant
```

It does compile in Windows (MinGW) but not in Linux.

Structure`my_multiboot_header` has to be initialized at compile time, not at load time.

```
#define LOAD_BASE 0x100000

typedef struct{
    int magic;
    int flags;
    int checksum;
    int header_addr;
    int load_addr;
    int load_end_addr;
    int bss_end_addr;
    int entry_addr;
    int mode_type;
    int width;
    int height;
    int depth;
} multiboot_header;
int kernel_boot(void);


const multiboot_header my_multiboot_header = {
    0x1BADB002,
    0x10003,
    - (0x10003 + 0x1BADB002),
    (int)&my_multiboot_header, // error: initializer element is not constant
    LOAD_BASE,
    0,
    0,
    (int)kernel_boot           // error: initializer element is not constant
};

int kernel_boot(){
    while(1);
    return 0xDEADC0de;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but remember that the multiboot specification says that all elements of the structure are 32-bit unsigned integers. The type `int` is first of all signed, and secondly have an implementation-defined size. Use a [standard fixed-width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) like `uint32_t` instead.

Comment: As for your problem, locations of functions or variables aren't known at compile-time, only at link-time, therefore you can't use their addresses as compile-time constants. There's a reason the multiboot header is typically initialized in an assembler file. Not to mention that you really need to set up your own stack, which is much easier to do in assembler as well.

Comment: thanks for the notice about "int" thing, i will fix that. And about multiboot header, I have seen this wiki https://wiki.osdev.org/Multiboot#Placing_the_Multiboot_struct which tells the structure can be initialized in C. and as i said it does compile in windows (MinGW)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What you write makes sense. But can you figure out why OP seems to be able to compile with MinGW?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Possibly different set of default flags for things like position-independent code and data between Windows and Linux?

Comment: I think it's because my windows has 32bit version of gcc and Linux was 64bit, so when i added `-m32` flag in Linux it solved the problem, I am not sure why though !

Comment: IIRC 64 and 32 bit builds use different [Application Binary Interfaces (ABI's)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). Furthermore, on a 64-bit system pointers are typically 64 bits wide, making it impossible to store them in 32-bit integer variables.